# Как взять данные с файла который хранится на компьютере при помощи JS?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу сделать игру "Виселица", и для нее подготовил текстовый документ со всевозможными словами. Однако теперь появилась проблема в невозможности прочитать этот документ при помощи JS

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли возможность сделать это на JS не прибегая к NODE

Comment: Конечно) текстовый документ сделайте например в формате json и дергайте его любым удобным вам способом) `fetch` например...

Comment: Если вы открываете просто `html` файл, то нет (либо использовать [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API)).

Comment: ну либо загружать файл через input type file и работать с ним, либо Fetch\аналоги